# ¿Cómo calcular la diferencia entre 2 fechas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Quería saber como se puede calcular la diferencia entre dos columnas del tipo DATE (FechaNacimiento y NOW()) para saber la edad de una persona.
Sé que se puede hacer con DATEDIFF, pero solo devuelve el valor en días, y yo quiero saber en años, y también que hay un método pero si son tipo DATETIME, y en mi caso no me sirve ese tipo de datos para mi dominio.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías probar con:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, FechaNacimiento, NOW()) AS edad FROM tabla;
```